# How to convert RTF to Markdown on the UNIX/OSX command line similar to pandoc

Tags: macos, unix, converters, markdown, rtf

How do I convert RTF (say from stdin) to Markdown with a command line tool under UNIX/OSX.

I am looking for something like [`pandoc`](http://pandoc.org/). However `pandoc` itself does not allow RTF as an *input* format. :-( So, I'd be happy either with a similar tool to `pandoc` or a pointer to an external RTF reader for `pandoc`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

On Mac OSX I can use the pre-installed [textutil](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/textutil.1.html) command for the RTF-to-HTML conversion, then convert via `pandoc` to markdown. So a command line which takes RTF from stdin and writes markdown to stdout looks like this:

```
textutil -stdin -convert html  -stdout | pandoc --from=html --to=markdown
```

Comment: This works terribly in my experience. `textutil` preserves none of my formatting and links, and the HTML is littered with useless classes.

Comment: @zool You can avoid (or at least significantly minimise the "class litter" by switching off some Pandoc extensions. I switch off `native_divs`, `native_spans`, `fenced_divs`, `header_attributes`, `auto_identifiers`, `inline_code_attributes`, `link_attributes` and `raw_attribute`. HTH, Leo

Comment: I tried this script. The links in the clipboard are all stripped off.

Comment: @Martin The current version of pandoc seems to support RTF as an input format. Maybe try that. It should be better at preserving links. If it works, post it as an answer here please.

Comment: I think the problem is not with pandoc but with textutil. I've found a [script](https://gist.github.com/rolandcrosby/c26571bf4e263f695d2f) that works (with minor changes). ```if encoded=`osascript -e 'the clipboard as «class HTML»'` 2>/dev/null; \
then echo $encoded \
    | perl -ne 'print chr foreach unpack("C*",pack("H*",substr($_,11,-3)))' \
    | pandoc --wrap=none -f HTML -t markdown; 
else pbpaste; 
fi```. To be host, I don't understand the code. Maybe `<<class HTML>>` makes a difference. I changed to `RTF` and the links are tripped off.

Comment: @Martin Sorry, I wasn't clear: I'meant you could try using pandoc _instead_ of textutil to read the RTF file. Anyway, I'm glad you found another solution.

Comment: @halloleo. Thanks. I did try pandoc before. The problem is I need to convert the text from the clipboard. padoc will simply strip off the links.

Answer (score 6):

Using [Ted](http://www.nllgg.nl/Ted/) and [pandoc](http://pandoc.org/) together, you should be able to do this:

```
Ted --saveTo text.rtf text.html
pandoc --from=html --to=markdown --out=text.md < text.html
```

Comment: Converting _rtl_ to _html_ can also easily be done with Apple's command **textutil** (see _man textutil_) And have a look at  (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043768/quickly-convert-rtf-doc-files-to-markdown-syntax-with-php)

Comment: @HeinrichGiesen Ups, didn't see your comment! Yes, that's what I found out as well: On OSX `textutil` is the way to go!

Comment: That sounds like the best answer for OS X; your question said you were looking for a cross platform solution so I didn't consider it. Glad you figured something out.

Comment: Ted 2.23 deb pkg is not installable on Debian 8.11, not even by dpkg command.

Comment: @pimgeek use the source

Comment: Also no need to downvote a perfectly good answer just because you can't figure out how to get software installed.

Comment: even if I compile from source, on my debian machine, the dependency does not satisfy ... I should be more explicit in my previous comment. :-(

Comment: @miken32 I noticed that my linux apt source.list had some issues, after fixing that I will try Ted again. I should not downvote your answer while being lazy to double-check. :-)

Comment: After I fixed the apt source.list, still get the following error, the dependency problem still persists... 

`E: Package 'libjpeg8' has no installation candidate`

`E: Package 'libtiff4' has no installation candidate`

Answer (score 4):

Pandoc now supports RTF as an input format, so you can use:

```sh
cat file.rtf | pandoc --from=rtf --to=markdown
```